# Orlik-Solomon algebra and hyperplane complements in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, positive-characteristic, hyperplane-arrangements

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p\geq 0$, $\underline H:=\{H_1,\dots, H_m\}$ a set of hyperplanes in $\mathbb A_k^n$ and $X:=\mathbb A^n-(\bigcup H_i)$.

Given a ring $R$ one can consider the Orlik-Solomon Algebra $OS(\underline H,R)$ of $\underline H$, which is defined as the exterior algebra $\bigwedge^{\bullet}(R^{m})$ modulo the ideal generated by the relations:

- $e_{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_s}$ if $H_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap H_{i_s}=\emptyset$
- $\sum^s_{r=1}(-1)^re_1\wedge \dots\wedge \widehat{e_{i_r}}\wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_s}$ if $H_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap H_{i_s}\neq \emptyset$ and $Codim(H_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap H_{i_s})<s$

If $k=\mathbb C$, then a famous theorem of Orlik-Solomon says that $H^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb Q)\simeq OS(\underline H,\mathbb Q)$ and can readily deduce a similar statement for $\ell$-adic cohomology if $k$ is of characteristic zero and $R=\mathbb Q_\ell$.

I'm looking for similar results when $k$ is of characteristic $p>0$ and $R=\mathbb Q_\ell$ for $\ell\neq p$. Looking online, there are various variants in positive characteristic (for example Theorem 3 in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82515319.pdf, Example 3.6 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01137.pdf) which describe the structure of the étale cohomology $H^{k}(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$ in each degree combinatorially, but (at the best of my weak understanding) they do not give the structure of $H^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$ as algebra.

The only reference that I have found giving the structure of $H^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$ as the Orlik-Solomon algebra is in sections 3.2.-3.3 of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601737.pdf in which the author computes the Motivic Cohomology of $X$ and then deduce from this computation that the various realisations have the descriprion as a Orlik-Solomon algebra.

I find this a little bit confusing and I don't know motivic cohomology enough, so, finally, my question is:

Is it possible to show the isomorphism $H^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)\simeq OS(\underline H,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ as algebra in positive characteristic without using motivic cohomology? If not, what is the obstruction?